# possible to use computed functions as an attrubute's value in template? vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, computed-properties

currently I am learning vue.js from youtube.  There is some logics to see if an html element should have which class.

In the tutorial, the logic is added in the `methods` which works fine, but if I add the logic into `computed` instead.  I am not able to use it as the attrubute's value

Is there a workaround? Just that somehow I feel like I should add it into `computed` so I tried it and error shows `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'answerItemClass' of undefined"` which I understand the error

I might be wrong to put it into `computed` just somehow this came up and wonder what if in the future there's something I really want to put into `computed` instead of `methods`, then would there be an easy workaround?

html example below

```
    <b-list-group-item
      v-for="(answer, index) in answers"
      v-html="answer"
      :key="index"
      :class="this.answerItemClass(index)"
      :disabled="answered"
      @click="selectAnswer(index)"
    >
    </b-list-group-item>
```

script, added into `computed` instead of `methods`

```
  computed: {
    answerItemClass(index) {
      let result = ''

      if (this.selectedIndex === index) result = 'selected';
      if ((this.answered) &&
        (this.correctAnswerIndex === index)
      ) result = 'correct';
      if ((this.answered) &&
        (this.selectedIndex === index) &&
        (this.correctAnswerIndex !== index)
      ) result = 'incorrect';

      return result;
    },
  }
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions and advises.

Comment: You don't need `this` in the html template

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an argument like that, I recommend continuing to use methods. Computed methods are cached and will only update with dependency changes. Methods will run every time they are called. While you could pass an argument into a computed, it's typically done for manipulating existing data in state somewhere and returning it.

This is covered in the [Vue documentation here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

And as the comment stated, remove any references of `this` from the template.

Answer (score 0):

This is my personal suggestion to provide a better way to achieve.

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      answers: [{
        answer: 'A',
        selected: false,
        correct: false
      }, {
        answer: 'B',
        selected: false,
        correct: true
      }, {
        answer: 'C',
        selected: false,
        correct: false
      }]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    selectAnswer(index) {
      this.answers = this.answers.map((v, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          v.selected = !v.selected
        } else {
          v.selected = false
        }
        return v
      })
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
ul>li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul>li.selected {
  background-color: #eee;
}

ul>li.correct {
  background-color: green;
}

ul>li.incorrect {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(answer, index) in answers" :key="index" :class="{'selected': answer.selected, 'correct': answer.selected&&answer.correct,'incorrect': answer.selected&&!answer.correct}" @click="selectAnswer(index)">{{answer.answer}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Put the state of the answer in the object of the array, and then determine which style to display by taking the state value when traversing the object.